# Android ignoring weight parameter on custom row

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have the following xml to build a custom row for my listview. It's working fine, but the status next to the address is being word wrapped which i don't want. In the past i've just set a weight and it's been fine, but it doesn't seem to be playing ball here.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Heres what happens on the phone:

[image]

Heres my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listviewonclick"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/Padding" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linHoz"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/cachecolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/MedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpacer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left"
            android:text=" | "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow"
            android:textSize="@dimen/MedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/MedText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linHoz2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_information" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/greenbuttons"
            android:text="Start" />

    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linarea"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.50" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnMap"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="28dp"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:background="@drawable/smallbluebutton"
          android:text="Map" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnInformation"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="28dp"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:background="@drawable/smallpurplebuttons"
          android:text="Information" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnProblems"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="110dp"
          android:layout_height="28dp"
          android:layout_margin="4dp"
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:background="@drawable/smallredbutton"
          android:text="Problems" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add android:sinleLine = "true" to a textview if you do not want word wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not enough space for both the `TextView`'s show all that text in a  be single line, its either warp or ellipsis. By default, `TextView`'s are multi-line, and will wrap text. To use ellipsis instead, add `android:singleLine="true"`.

About proportioning the text width:
set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for all Views participating in weighted layout.
Assign weights to each using `android:layout_weight` in a proportion. E.g. `0.3` for download `TextView` and `0.7` for address `TextView`. This will give 30% space to first View and 70% of space to second view.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `layout_weight` attribute to address label only. You can set `layout_width="0dip"` for better performance. And also set layout orientation explicitly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linHoz"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpacer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" | "/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Address"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Very very long text goes here. Very very long text goes here." />

</LinearLayout>
```